# Aws DynamoDb Issues at the time of import/export data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

At the time of import/export data in DynamoDB getting the below error:
Terminated with errors The requested number of instances exceeds your EC2 quota??

Here I am using t2.micro ec2 instances and perform the below steps:
create one pipeline for export data into dynamoDB from s3 but emr every time fails due to the above error.

Kindly suggest any solutions..??